# Bing Maps Maximum Transactions on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a wp8 app, which it will integrate a bing map control.

When I created a bing maps key, I noticed that Basic Key has maximum limitation as below:

```
Mobile and Windows Store Apps: Maximum 50,000 cumulative billable transactions within any 24-hour period.
```

If my app's user is more enough, is this means I have to give up bing map?

Comment: What does the documentation say?   Although I'd be surprised if the average user would come anywhere near 50,000 billable transactions in a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic key for Bing maps is limited to 50,000 *billable* transactions across your app in any 24 hour period. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx) it looks like using the WP control is not billable so you shouldn't have an issue.

That said, if you have an app that is generating over 50,000 map loads a day then you should be able to cover the cost of the Enterprise license (which is effectively unlimited) and not have to worry about the extra usage. While there are no public pricing options for this key, you can contact Bing directly (under the Enterprise Key section of [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx)) to discuss.